# update div that contains include file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm new to PHP and I am trying to update part of the div which contains include file like so:

```
<div id="hello"><?php  include("include_file.php");?></div>
```

On ajax success I want to update that div so that it shows me the updated field. I tried
this:

```
$(document).on('click','a#relatedUser', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'loadmsg.php',
            type:"GET",
            async:false,
            success:function(data){
              $('.loadmsg').html(data);  
              $('div#hello').load('include_file.php');

            }
        });

});
```

But it's getting the session problem, and I can't include session in the "include_file.php" file.
I tried lot but I am not getting the solution. I'll be thankful for your help.

Comment: From the context, it seems that this information might be helpful: always keep in mind, that javascript runs on the client side, and php is executed on the server side...

Comment: what do you want to display in the div? The jquery won't know about php, it will just see the result of the 'include_file.php'.

Comment: on sucess u can load include file and after that append the response html data to the div hello

Comment: What exactly is *"the session problem"*? If `include_file.php` depends on session information, you need to start a session there when a session has not yet been started (in an ajax request for example).

Comment: @bicycle I encountered posts here on [SO], where clarifying this bit helped a lot... So: yes, really. Even though to you and me, it sounds exactly as if I said that the sky is blue...

Comment: @jeroen i already included the session in file from which i m sending the ajax request to third file and on success i wants to reload include_file.php so that it'll show me the updated record that i updated from third file.

Comment: @ppeterka hmmmm i would object to that, sky is currently black here :( dunno why...

Comment: @KumariManisha it might be better for you to first read a good book about php and jquery and how it would all work together. You'll be likely doing a lot of things the wrong way and therefore causing you to redo it all over again later on.

Comment: @bicycle not blue here either - and I (I assume you too) can run JavaScript on the server side too. That's why I chose that sentence. I don't know what is your problem with me trying to help someone having troubles by trying to interface him on his own level without confusing him. OP clearly needs some experience to be confident around these things, I wanted to give him a nudge in the right direction with an easy explanation. This was like saying the gravitational constant on Earth is 10. On a next level of experience, g=9.81. Next, altitude is a parameter to g... Do you understand me now?

Comment: @ppeterka If OP doesn't know the difference between js and php he better read a good book about stuff like jQuery and PHP. Otherwise he'll be doing all the wrong things and asking questions nobody understands like "update div that contains include file".

Comment: @bicycle I have the strong feeling, that OP knows that reading books on jQuery and PHP would be a good long time strategy. Apparently, with this, you invented the solution to all the questions: read the books about the subject. But does that solve the problem at hand? No. He will post 10 similar questions in a couple of minutes, as obviously, he'd have to hunt down the book, order it, wait for it, read it, but he has to get the job done. You'll be amused how many of these questions end in "ASAP". I gave him a "stable point in the universe". And you?

Comment: @ppeterka at least when OP reads the book he'll be able to create understandable questions that others might find useful as well. Now this question is so hard to understand you're even unable to know what he's looking for. It's like going to a car forum and ask "inflate tire that contains the petrol"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's load is shorthand for another ajax request to your server (to `include_file.php`).

This is a separate request and no (session-) variables from any of your other scripts will be available in that script when you call it in a separate request. To mimic that behaviour, just try to open `include_file.php` directly in your browser.

So if you need session variables to be available in that script, you need to start a session if a session has not been started already. You can do that for example like:

```
if (session_id() === '')
{
     // a session has not yet been started
     session_start();
}
```

at the top of `include_file.php`.

Answer (score 2):

From code what you provide, it's not clear type of problem what you have.

I can guess, what you need to add `session_start();` into beginning of both include_file.php and loadmsg.php

Comment: i already included the session in file from which i m sending the ajax request to third file and on success i wants to reload include_file.php so that it'll show me the updated record that i updated from third file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which field or element you are trying to update. ... so I think this is perhaps what you want :

HTML :

```
   <div id="hello">These are the contents that will be updated on the ajax call </div>
   <a id="relatedUser" href="#" >Click Here </a>

   <script>
     $(document).ready( $("#relatedUser").click(
     function () {
     $.ajax({
            url:'/path/to/include_file.php',
            type:"GET",
            success:function(data){
              $("#hello:).html(data);  
            }
        });
} )
```

);

Comment: i already included the session in file from which i m sending the ajax request to third file and on success i wants to reload include_file.php so that it'll show me the updated record that i updated from third file.